# SQL services wont start due to incorrect drive letter

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL services wont start due to incorrect drive letter after windows restore](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33123/sql-services-wont-start-due-to-incorrect-drive-letter-after-windows-restore)

SQL services wont start due to incorrect drive letter after windows restore

Had a server crash, was successfully able to reinstall windows and restore the server SQL and all the necessary services were already installed after restore. all the sql databases were unharmed they were on a different partion.

Only problem the windows drives letters are wrong. So the services are pointed to the incorrect drive letter. I cant change the services in regedit or change the drive letter in disk management. Is there a way to do a repair in SQL add remove programs to associate's the necessary services with the correct drive letter?

Here's a example of the services
Path to executable
I:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\

only problem the actual drive letter is E:

Services that wont start
SQL SERVER
SQL SERVER AGENT
SQL Server Analysis
SQL Server Analysis Services
SQL Server Integration Services
SQL Server Reporting Services

Solutions I have tried
Changing drive letter within disk management
Tried Substitute command

Comment: The SO question was migrated here, so we can close this as duplicate.